# Drupal 7, Views, Better Exposed Filters and SEO friendly urls

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I know there are several topics on this issue but I can't find any feasible solutions for BEF Filtering with SEO friendly URLs.

The only feasible hint i found is, to use hook_url_inbound_alter and hook_url_outbound_alter.
I tried to use both in a module but i don't get rid of my problem... Maybe anyone here can help me?

**My "Setup":**

I'm using Views (V. 7.x-3.7), Better Exposed Filters, and the latest Drupal 7 version.

*The Filters are following (all based on taxonomy terms / used as links in the front end):*

- Activities: Field name: field_sportart_tid[0]=1; Terms: Bike, Family, Run, Triathlon, Ski Alpin ...
- Countries: Field name: field_country_tid=12; Terms: Austria, Croatia, Italy
- Regions: Field name: field_region_tid[0]=22: Terms: F.e. Austria: Carinthia, Uperaustria, Salzburg....

The taxonomy terms should be logically combined so that you have a url which looks something like this: /bike-run/austria/carinthia-upperaustria/

So anyone can help me to solve this problem?

Regards

Marc

Answer (score 0):

You can use [views_url_path_arguments](https://drupal.org/project/views_url_path_arguments) module.

Similar question here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22989/changing-url-of-exposed-filter

Comment: I've seen all of these posts already, but i'm not able to solve it at all, therefore I asked here that questione ;).